# Get receiver email address using c# pop3

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail, pop3, email-headers

That sounds funny. But in Gmail, we get list of both sent and received emails in pop3. So i need to get email address of sent emails (receiver).
hint: for received emails we check email like this
message.Headers.From.Address
But i need info of sent emails.

Comment: What is your question again?! SO is a forum for developers, who have done some work, and are stuck with a programming question. You don't provide any problem for us to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

```
foreach (OpenPop.Mime.Header.RfcMailAddress objectItem in message.Headers.To)
{ email_to += objectItem.Address.ToString(); }
```